# How is mac address shared from one host to another?

Tags: networking, routing

If i have two systems in the same network, how is the mac address shared in the network access layer? By this, I mean how is the destination mac address known to the source?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. I can't tell from your question if IPv4 or IPv6 is more important so I'll primarily link an article discussing IPv6 changes with what it replaces in IPv4; it should answer the question and others may provide better answers.

Answer (score 1):

General topology discovery may be done via Address Resolution Protocol (ARP, IPv4) or Neighbor Discovery Protocol (NDP, IPv6).

You may be familiar with broadcast addresses in a TCP/IP subnet, by convention the last available address in your subnet. For example in 192.168.1.0/24, the broadcast address is by convention (but not always by configuration) 192.168.1.255.

Getting those IP addresses requires knowing who to get them from (you can't send a (good) DHCP request if you don't even know what network you're supposed to use), so packets are sent/monitored at the media access control (MAC) level to discover the default gateway and some other things. Just like the example above, there are also broadcast MAC addresses; it may help to look at each octet of the above broadcast address in hexadecimal:

192.168.1.255 = C0.A8.01.FF

The key item is the FF. So what's the broadcast MAC address?

FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF

*Note that the first three FF's usually identify the manufacturer, which is how protocol analyzers and other systems can identify hardware*

I've got to post this before my site shuts down so you may also want to review [this reading material](http://www.cisco.com/web/about/security/intelligence/ipv6_first_hop.html). I mentioned it in the comment above; it's an example of IPv6 discovery compared to IPv4 (from a security perspective) and may provide some context, also a [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address) on broadcasts with a hint towards ARP.